# If I know : $U_n(x) \sim \frac{A_n}{x^2}$, how can I know the equivalent to $\sum_{n\geq0} U_n(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am facing a problem in which I know the equivalent of a term that I sum: $U_n(x) \sim \frac{A_n}{x^2}$. However, I am interested in the equivalent of my serie (for $x \rightarrow \infty$).

I tried "to see" to consider that I can just sum the equivalent but in my problem it gives me the good power but not the good coefficient : I find

$$\sum_{n\geq0} U_n(x) \sim \frac{\sum A_n}{x^2}$$

The $x^2$ is ok but the value $\sum A_n$ doesn't match my numeric estimation.

I know that if $a_n \sim b_n$ and $c_n \sim d_n$ then it is wrong in general to say $a_n+c_n \sim b_n + d_n$. This is why I have my problem here.

Comment: I think you need some specifics about how fast/well $U_n(x) \sim \frac{A_n}{x^2}$. If all you have is the limit asymptotics, that is not enough to sum the infinite series.

Comment: @quarague Actually I can have a perturbative expansion to any power of $\frac{1}{x}$. Also, the coefficient $A_n$ is $A_n=\frac{\pi^4}{4*8^2}c_n^2$ with $c_n^2=e^{-x}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. I don't know if this is enough

Comment: If you have an expansion in powers of $\frac{1}{x}$ you should get a bound on $|U_n(x)-\frac{A_n}{x^2}|$. If you sum these bounds over $n$, can you show that the sum of bounds converges to zero? Looking at the size of the sum of bounds relative to $x$ should also give you an idea about whether your numeric estimation is any good.

Comment: @quarague I might be able to compute the sum you propose but I'm not sure to totally get the point. Let's assume that the sum of these bounds converge to $0$, what would it tell me about the analytic equivalent of the serie for $x \rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: If you can show that the sum of the error bounds converges to zero than this proves that your main formula is correct.

Comment: Your notation suggests (to me at least) that $A_n$ does not depends on $x$ , but your comment tells otherwise : if so, it's hard to understand the divisor $x^2$ (as it could be part of $A_n$)...